# Using variables in typeScript graphQL code generator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, code-generation, apollo-client

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/tooling/apollo-codegen/typescript-graphql-code-generator-generate-graphql-types/) to auto generate the schema of my graphql endpoint in my front application.

However now I need to use variables, so I did something like this:

```
export const GET_TODO = gql`
  query GetTodo($id: Int!) {
    todos(id: $id) {
        id
        text
        completed
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to know if there is a way I can get the variable type "automatically" without having to redefine it in the front.
E.g.

```
...
 query GetTodo($id: AutoGeneratedTodoIdType) {
...
```

PS: I am using react, in case there are framework/library specific solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, you will usually have exported types in the generated file such as `GetTodoVariables`